# Using a string variable to hold the css

Tags: scrapy

using python scrapy

I want to replace this: response.css("a.btn::attr(href)")
With this:

mycssstring = "a.btn::attr(href)"
response.css(mycssstring)

so I can make a more dynamic spider.

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: Hi Thanks for getting back to me. Sorry just me being a Muppet! trying to learn python and scrapy at same time. Just put my string variable in the wrong place. It's working ok now. Thanks again Matt